# How to layout files in a monorepo pattern? What is the best practice?

Tags: git, version-control, monorepo

I'm convinced to the google's monorepo pattern, which is to put all projects in one single repository. But how should I put files in a monorepo? I have googled a lot and found no answers. I can think of some possible ways:

1. group files by project;
2. group files by language;
3. group files by department.

Which is the best way?

Comment: I believe that at Google at top level they split by language. However I'm not sure. I only saw some traits in Bazel code (opensourced version of their internal build system - Blaze). Sometimes folders like `/java` or `/javatest` where mentioned.